# Comparison between pointer and integer in string class - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char, implicit-conversion, string-literals

I'm new to C++.

```
string str = "WWWHBBB";
if(str[mid] == "H" && str[0] != "W") return; // corrected after comments for second operand
```

The above line with `if` condition gives me an error.

> Comparison between pointer and integer ('std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::value_type' (aka 'char') and 'const char *')

I have searched the internet enough to know that array style access is fine in strings. Error basically is pointing out comparison about pointer and integer. Really? I thought I was comparing character `H` to another character in string `str`.

I tried if `str[mid]` really returns an iterator I should do `*str[mid]`. Nah! Didn't work either.

Comment: Double quotes mean it's a c-string (`const char*`), if you want a character literal, use single quotes.

Comment: C++ isn't JavaScript.  The types of quotes you use makes a difference.

Comment: Gotcha... Learning on the fly and writing my programs. Please love me for it.

Comment: Single quotes for single characters.  Double quotes for text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression of the if statement

```
 if(str[mid] == "H" && str[mid] != "W") return;
```

the string literals "H" and "W" that have the type `const char[2]` are implicitly converted to pointers to their first characters of the type `const char *`.

So you are trying to compare a character returned by the expression `str[mid]` with a pointer.

Instead of the string literals you need to use character literals like to compare characters

```
 if(str[mid] == 'H' && str[mid] != 'W') return;
```

You could also write like

```
 if(str[mid] == *"H" && str[mid] != *"W") return;
```

or

```
 if(str[mid] == "H"[0] && str[mid] != "W"[0]) return;
```

dereferencing the pointers but this will be confusing

Pay attention to that if `str[mid] == 'H'` then the second operand will always yield true. So it is enough to write

```
 if( str[mid] == 'H' ) return;
```

Comment: As `'H' != 'W'`, we might even just write `if (str[mid] == 'H') return;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 A good remark. I even did not look through the condition.:)

Comment: Hey Vlad, That's all good but I did not understand why would it say integer and not char for LHS.
@Jarod42 the second operand was supposed to be str[0]. thanks :)

Comment: @kushalvm The type char belongs to standard integer types.

Comment: Oops! I should finish this formal reading first I guess for the language. Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to compare with a single `char`

```
if (str[mid] == 'H' && str[mid] != 'W') return;
```

Note that double-quotes in this case refer to a `const char[]` whereas single-quotes refer to a single `char`.

The warning is telling you that the only way to make those comparisons in your case would be to compare the lhs `char` (result of `str[mid]`) to the rhs would be to let the array decay to `const char*` and compare the pointer address to the `char`.

Comment: Can you please point me to a good but full fledged tutorial/reference for C++?

Comment: @kushalvm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list